# Will Indexes affect for every insert even I escape that column from insert statement?

Tags: mysql, indexing

I am using MYSQL in my application development as my DB.

I want to clarify a thing.

Imagine There is a table called test.

Columns are col1,col2,col3,col4.
these columns have separate indexes. that mean 4 indexes.

I am inserting a record just to col1 and col2.

When you have a index in a column insert operation have a cost.

My question is. ----

So when I insert records only to one and two Do I have an affect from col3 and col4 ?
Will indexes will fire for every insert or will it fire if I do insert to those columns?

Answer (score 2):

Let's get a basic fact straight: in an RDBMS there is no such thing that you insert a record for only a selected number fields in a table. If you insert a record, then **all** fields within that table will have a value for that record. That value may be a `null` value, but it is there.

Not to mention another fact, that columns may have non-null default values, so executing an insert that does not specify value for them will still result a non-null value to be stored.

Mysql indexes even null values, so if you have separate indexes for each column, then mysql has to update all indexes when a new record is inserted into the table, regardless how many fields are specifically assigned value within the insert.